# Exception: no routes for location: /level1 in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-go-router

I am trying to build navigation between screens and it doesn't work between two specific screens.
My code on clicked button that should lead to the second screen:

```
    child: FilledButton(
                      onPressed: () => GoRouter.of(context).go('/level1'),
                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                primary: Color(0xFF000000),
                                fixedSize: Size(157, 40),
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFF8383)
                                 ), // Background Color
                        child: const Text('START')
                  ),
```

main.dart code with routes:

```
     GoRoute(
path: '/level1',
builder:(context, state) => Level1Screen(key: Key('level1')),
),
```

level1screen code:

```
   class Level1Screen extends StatefulWidget {

   const Level1Screen({super.key});

   @override
   State<Level1Screen> createState() => _Level1ScreenState();
   }

   class _Level1ScreenState extends State<Level1Screen> {
   static final _log = Logger('level1');
```

Comment: according to GoRouter documentation, you should use `MaterialApp.router` widget as the root Widget of application. are you using `MaterialApp.router` Widget?

Answer (score 3):

If your passing in `pathParameters`. 
Make sure none of the values is an empty string: `pathParameters: {'back': ''});`

Answer (score 1):

You missing `/` in your GoRoute path definition.

**UPD** This example is working:

main.dart

```
final _router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder:(context, state) => const Level2Screen(key: Key('level2')),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/level1',
      builder:(context, state) => const Level1Screen(key: Key('level1')),
    )
  ]
);

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}
```

Level1 class

```
class Level1Screen extends StatefulWidget {

  const Level1Screen({super.key});

  @override
  State<Level1Screen> createState() => _Level1ScreenState();
}

class _Level1ScreenState extends State<Level1Screen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Level1 Screen'
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Level2 class

```
class Level2Screen extends StatefulWidget {

  const Level2Screen({super.key});

  @override
  State<Level2Screen> createState() => _Level2ScreenState();
}

class _Level2ScreenState extends State<Level2Screen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FilledButton(
            onPressed: () => GoRouter.of(context).go('/level1'),
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Color(0xFF000000),
                fixedSize: Size(157, 40),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFF8383)
            ), // Background Color
            child: const Text('START')
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work: Exception: no routes for location: /level1

Comment: @ElenaEpshtein I have updated the answer. Check if your GoRouter config is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Already fixed the problem by re-running flutter